# Adding an existing Editor from a Perspective to MultiPageEditor

Tags: eclipse, perspective

is there a possible way to extend a perspective with the extension point `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` in such a way that its assosioated perspective editor can be added to my MutliPageEditor?

Is there a way to listen for the editor to open and then creating a MutliPageEditor where the opended editor will be added to it?

Comment: You should overthink your concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

The perspective extensions don't have any support for merging editors like this.

You can listen for editors (and views) opening but there is no way change the structure of the editor that has opened.

Comment: Is it possible to close the editor of the perspective and open my own MutliPageEditor adding to it a new instance of the perspective editor?

Comment: Closing an editor is easy. A multipage editor can include a specific ordinary editor if you know the editor's main class so that you call `new` on it. I can't see a way to include an editor if all you know is the editor's id (but I'm not sure about this).

Comment: I found the editor class of the CDT plug-in and call ```new org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.editor.CEditor()``` on it. MultiPageEditor works with this. Eclipse warns me with 'Discouraged access: The constructor 'CEditor()' is not API (restriction on required library org.eclipse.cdt.ui_xxx.jar'. Do you see any problem with that when my plug-in includes the CDT plug-in in the dependencies?

Comment: Anything in an **internal** package is not an official API. This means the developers are free to change it at any time. So your code might suddenly break on a new release (even a patch release) or it might not work on older versions. It is up to you to decide if this is acceptable or not.